# Need Assistance Interpreting System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a production system (C# Winform) app that is intermittently crashing in Windows.  The error message in the application log is below.  I have reviewed our source code and do not believe that we are using any unsafe or unmanaged code.  We are using 3rd party libraries and a COM library.  Can someone please help me interpret the error message below and provide some guidance on how I might start tracking down the source of this error?

```
Application: purefuel_fi.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseMove(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form)
   at Fuel.Program.onlyOneAppInstance(Int32)
   at Fuel.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Comment: If you are using Windows Forms then you are eventually calling the unmanaged Windows API. So you are using unmanaged code. The COM library is probably unmanaged code, and your 3rd party library could also contain unmanaged code. What appears to be happening here is that a bad memory pointer is being passed to the CallWindowProc Windows API function.